# Converting Hierarchical DOM-Tree XML Files: Can XSLT convert to a "flattened" XML file without losing data?

Tags: xml, dom, xslt, transform, relational

I am working with a batch of XML files that come every month. They all follow the same DOM tree structure and they do not come with schema files. Here is a sample:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="ISO-8859-1" ?>
<REPORT><REPORT-DTL><REPORT-ID>PCRP60R1-C</REPORT-ID><REPORT-DATE>2020-10-01</REPORT-DATE><REPORT-NAME>OUTSIDE USE REPORT (PATIENTS WITH SIGNED CONSENT)</REPORT-NAME><REPORT-PERIOD-START>2020-09-01</REPORT-PERIOD-START><REPORT-PERIOD-END>2020-09-30</REPORT-PERIOD-END></REPORT-DTL>
  <GROUP><GROUP-DTL><GROUP-ID>DoctorAGroup1234</GROUP-ID><GROUP-TYPE>HOSP</GROUP-TYPE><GROUP-NAME>COUNTY HOSP</GROUP-NAME></GROUP-DTL>
    <PROVIDER><PROVIDER-DTL><PROVIDER-NUMBER>DoctorAID1234</PROVIDER-NUMBER><PROVIDER-LAST-NAME>DoctorALastname</PROVIDER-LAST-NAME><PROVIDER-FIRST-NAME>DoctorAFirstname</PROVIDER-FIRST-NAME><PROVIDER-MIDDLE-NAME>DoctorAMiddleName</PROVIDER-MIDDLE-NAME></PROVIDER-DTL>
      <PATIENT><PATIENT-DTL><PATIENT-HEALTH-NUMBER>PatientANumber1234</PATIENT-HEALTH-NUMBER><PATIENT-LAST-NAME>PatientALastname</PATIENT-LAST-NAME><PATIENT-FIRST-NAME>PatientAFirstname</PATIENT-FIRST-NAME><PATIENT-BIRTHDATE>1941-02-11</PATIENT-BIRTHDATE><PATIENT-SEX>M</PATIENT-SEX></PATIENT-DTL>
        <SERVICE-DTL1><SERVICE-LOC> </SERVICE-LOC><SERVICE-DATE>PatientAServiceDate2020-09-07</SERVICE-DATE><SERVICE-CODE>PatientAServiceCodeABC1</SERVICE-CODE><SERVICE-DESCRIPTION>PatientAServiceDescription-Facelift</SERVICE-DESCRIPTION><SERVICE-AMT>PatientAServiceAmount8.90</SERVICE-AMT></SERVICE-DTL1>
      </PATIENT>
      <PATIENT><PATIENT-DTL><PATIENT-HEALTH-NUMBER>PatientBNumber1235</PATIENT-HEALTH-NUMBER><PATIENT-LAST-NAME>PatientBLastname</PATIENT-LAST-NAME><PATIENT-FIRST-NAME>PatientBFirstname</PATIENT-FIRST-NAME><PATIENT-BIRTHDATE>1955-10-11</PATIENT-BIRTHDATE><PATIENT-SEX>F</PATIENT-SEX></PATIENT-DTL>
        <SERVICE-DTL1><SERVICE-LOC> </SERVICE-LOC><SERVICE-DATE>PatientBServiceDate2020-12-08</SERVICE-DATE><SERVICE-CODE>PatientBServiceCodeABC2</SERVICE-CODE><SERVICE-DESCRIPTION>PatientBServiceDescription-Checkup</SERVICE-DESCRIPTION><SERVICE-AMT>PatientBServiceAmount10.50</SERVICE-AMT></SERVICE-DTL1>
      </PATIENT>
      <PATIENT><PATIENT-DTL><PATIENT-HEALTH-NUMBER>PatientCNumber1236</PATIENT-HEALTH-NUMBER><PATIENT-LAST-NAME>PatientCLastname</PATIENT-LAST-NAME><PATIENT-FIRST-NAME>PatientCFirstname</PATIENT-FIRST-NAME><PATIENT-BIRTHDATE>1965-02-07</PATIENT-BIRTHDATE><PATIENT-SEX>F</PATIENT-SEX></PATIENT-DTL>
        <SERVICE-DTL1><SERVICE-LOC> </SERVICE-LOC><SERVICE-DATE>PatientCServiceDate2020-11-11</SERVICE-DATE><SERVICE-CODE>PatientCServiceCodeABC3</SERVICE-CODE><SERVICE-DESCRIPTION>PatientCServiceDescription-X-Ray</SERVICE-DESCRIPTION><SERVICE-AMT>PatientCServiceAmount18.00</SERVICE-AMT></SERVICE-DTL1>
      </PATIENT>
      <PATIENT><PATIENT-DTL><PATIENT-HEALTH-NUMBER>PatientDNumber1237</PATIENT-HEALTH-NUMBER><PATIENT-LAST-NAME>PatientDLastname</PATIENT-LAST-NAME><PATIENT-FIRST-NAME>PatientDFirstname</PATIENT-FIRST-NAME><PATIENT-BIRTHDATE>1975-07-09</PATIENT-BIRTHDATE><PATIENT-SEX>M</PATIENT-SEX></PATIENT-DTL>
        <SERVICE-DTL1><SERVICE-LOC> </SERVICE-LOC><SERVICE-DATE>PatientDServiceDate2020-01-10</SERVICE-DATE><SERVICE-CODE>PatientDServiceCodeABC4</SERVICE-CODE><SERVICE-DESCRIPTION>PatientDServiceDescription-Nose Cleaning</SERVICE-DESCRIPTION><SERVICE-AMT>PatientDServiceAmount6.00</SERVICE-AMT></SERVICE-DTL1>
      </PATIENT>
    </PROVIDER>
  </GROUP>
</REPORT>
```

Note the hierarchical structure of the code. All of the PATIENT data "belongs" to a parent PROVIDER node. Each PROCEDURE "belongs" to the PATIENT who supersedes it. The XML code describes
[these](https://i.stack.imgur.com/kt4Kc.png) 4 interrelated tables.

My database software can't import these interrelated tables from an XML file -- my database app can't follow the hierarchy of the code.

Instead, I can import the data if it were "flattened", and the interrelated nodes were "unpacked" (and replicated). [Here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/paXHc.jpg) is how I would like my flattened table to look upon import. Yes, it has lots of redundancy -- the first 12 columns of this new table are identical for every record. (That's OK, I can eliminate the redundancies later; at this point, I just want to read in all the data.)

Here is the XML code that generated the flattened table in the image above:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="ISO-8859-1" ?>

<REPORT>
    <ImportedTable>
<REPORT-ID>PCRP60R1-C</REPORT-ID><REPORT-DATE>2020-10-01</REPORT-DATE><REPORT-NAME>OUTSIDE USE REPORT (PATIENTS WITH SIGNED CONSENT)</REPORT-NAME><REPORT-PERIOD-START>2020-09-01</REPORT-PERIOD-START><REPORT-PERIOD-END>2020-09-30</REPORT-PERIOD-END>
  <GROUP-ID>DoctorAGroup1234</GROUP-ID><GROUP-TYPE>HOSP</GROUP-TYPE><GROUP-NAME>COUNTY HOSP</GROUP-NAME>
<PROVIDER-NUMBER>DoctorAID1234</PROVIDER-NUMBER><PROVIDER-LAST-NAME>DoctorALastname</PROVIDER-LAST-NAME><PROVIDER-FIRST-NAME>DoctorAFirstname</PROVIDER-FIRST-NAME><PROVIDER-MIDDLE-NAME>DoctorAMiddleName</PROVIDER-MIDDLE-NAME>
<PATIENT-HEALTH-NUMBER>PatientANumber1234</PATIENT-HEALTH-NUMBER><PATIENT-LAST-NAME>PatientALastname</PATIENT-LAST-NAME><PATIENT-FIRST-NAME>PatientAFirstname</PATIENT-FIRST-NAME><PATIENT-BIRTHDATE>1941-02-11</PATIENT-BIRTHDATE><PATIENT-SEX>M</PATIENT-SEX>
        <SERVICE-LOC> </SERVICE-LOC><SERVICE-DATE>PatientAServiceDate2020-09-07</SERVICE-DATE><SERVICE-CODE>PatientAServiceCodeABC1</SERVICE-CODE><SERVICE-DESCRIPTION>PatientAServiceDescription-Facelift</SERVICE-DESCRIPTION><SERVICE-AMT>PatientAServiceAmount8.90</SERVICE-AMT>
    </ImportedTable>

    <ImportedTable>
<REPORT-ID>PCRP60R1-C</REPORT-ID><REPORT-DATE>2020-10-01</REPORT-DATE><REPORT-NAME>OUTSIDE USE REPORT (PATIENTS WITH SIGNED CONSENT)</REPORT-NAME><REPORT-PERIOD-START>2020-09-01</REPORT-PERIOD-START><REPORT-PERIOD-END>2020-09-30</REPORT-PERIOD-END>
  <GROUP-ID>DoctorAGroup1234</GROUP-ID><GROUP-TYPE>HOSP</GROUP-TYPE><GROUP-NAME>COUNTY HOSP</GROUP-NAME>
<PROVIDER-NUMBER>DoctorAID1234</PROVIDER-NUMBER><PROVIDER-LAST-NAME>DoctorALastname</PROVIDER-LAST-NAME><PROVIDER-FIRST-NAME>DoctorAFirstname</PROVIDER-FIRST-NAME><PROVIDER-MIDDLE-NAME>DoctorAMiddleName</PROVIDER-MIDDLE-NAME>
<PATIENT-HEALTH-NUMBER>PatientBNumber1235</PATIENT-HEALTH-NUMBER><PATIENT-LAST-NAME>PatientBLastname</PATIENT-LAST-NAME><PATIENT-FIRST-NAME>PatientBFirstname</PATIENT-FIRST-NAME><PATIENT-BIRTHDATE>1955-10-11</PATIENT-BIRTHDATE><PATIENT-SEX>F</PATIENT-SEX>
        <SERVICE-LOC> </SERVICE-LOC><SERVICE-DATE>PatientBServiceDate2020-12-08</SERVICE-DATE><SERVICE-CODE>PatientBServiceCodeABC2</SERVICE-CODE><SERVICE-DESCRIPTION>PatientBServiceDescription-Checkup</SERVICE-DESCRIPTION><SERVICE-AMT>PatientBServiceAmount10.50</SERVICE-AMT>
    </ImportedTable>

    <ImportedTable>
<REPORT-ID>PCRP60R1-C</REPORT-ID><REPORT-DATE>2020-10-01</REPORT-DATE><REPORT-NAME>OUTSIDE USE REPORT (PATIENTS WITH SIGNED CONSENT)</REPORT-NAME><REPORT-PERIOD-START>2020-09-01</REPORT-PERIOD-START><REPORT-PERIOD-END>2020-09-30</REPORT-PERIOD-END>
<GROUP-ID>DoctorAGroup1234</GROUP-ID><GROUP-TYPE>HOSP</GROUP-TYPE><GROUP-NAME>COUNTY HOSP</GROUP-NAME>
    <PROVIDER-NUMBER>DoctorAID1234</PROVIDER-NUMBER><PROVIDER-LAST-NAME>DoctorALastname</PROVIDER-LAST-NAME><PROVIDER-FIRST-NAME>DoctorAFirstname</PROVIDER-FIRST-NAME><PROVIDER-MIDDLE-NAME>DoctorAMiddleName</PROVIDER-MIDDLE-NAME>
      <PATIENT-HEALTH-NUMBER>PatientCNumber1236</PATIENT-HEALTH-NUMBER><PATIENT-LAST-NAME>PatientCLastname</PATIENT-LAST-NAME><PATIENT-FIRST-NAME>PatientCFirstname</PATIENT-FIRST-NAME><PATIENT-BIRTHDATE>1965-02-07</PATIENT-BIRTHDATE><PATIENT-SEX>F</PATIENT-SEX>
        <SERVICE-LOC> </SERVICE-LOC><SERVICE-DATE>PatientCServiceDate2020-11-11</SERVICE-DATE><SERVICE-CODE>PatientCServiceCodeABC3</SERVICE-CODE><SERVICE-DESCRIPTION>PatientCServiceDescription-X-Ray</SERVICE-DESCRIPTION><SERVICE-AMT>PatientCServiceAmount18.00</SERVICE-AMT>
    </ImportedTable>

    <ImportedTable>
<REPORT-ID>PCRP60R1-C</REPORT-ID><REPORT-DATE>2020-10-01</REPORT-DATE><REPORT-NAME>OUTSIDE USE REPORT (PATIENTS WITH SIGNED CONSENT)</REPORT-NAME><REPORT-PERIOD-START>2020-09-01</REPORT-PERIOD-START><REPORT-PERIOD-END>2020-09-30</REPORT-PERIOD-END>
<GROUP-ID>DoctorAGroup1234</GROUP-ID><GROUP-TYPE>HOSP</GROUP-TYPE><GROUP-NAME>COUNTY HOSP</GROUP-NAME>
    <PROVIDER-NUMBER>DoctorAID1234</PROVIDER-NUMBER><PROVIDER-LAST-NAME>DoctorALastname</PROVIDER-LAST-NAME><PROVIDER-FIRST-NAME>DoctorAFirstname</PROVIDER-FIRST-NAME><PROVIDER-MIDDLE-NAME>DoctorAMiddleName</PROVIDER-MIDDLE-NAME>
      <PATIENT-HEALTH-NUMBER>PatientDNumber1237</PATIENT-HEALTH-NUMBER><PATIENT-LAST-NAME>PatientDLastname</PATIENT-LAST-NAME><PATIENT-FIRST-NAME>PatientDFirstname</PATIENT-FIRST-NAME><PATIENT-BIRTHDATE>1975-07-09</PATIENT-BIRTHDATE><PATIENT-SEX>M</PATIENT-SEX>
     <SERVICE-LOC> </SERVICE-LOC><SERVICE-DATE>PatientDServiceDate2020-01-10</SERVICE-DATE><SERVICE-CODE>PatientDServiceCodeABC4</SERVICE-CODE><SERVICE-DESCRIPTION>PatientDServiceDescription-Nose Cleaning</SERVICE-DESCRIPTION><SERVICE-AMT>PatientDServiceAmount6.00</SERVICE-AMT>
    </ImportedTable>
</REPORT>
```

So, my question is whether XSLT can transform from the top XML file into the bottom one. Note that, in the converted XML file, I am only interested in retaining nodes containing text. (Any non-text nodes from the original file can safely be ignored in this transformation.) Is there code that could make this transformation? (Note: I have been reading a number of threads dealing with XML conversions but this situation is unusual because of the relational structure of this data set. If this question has been answered elsewhere, please let me know!)

Thanks very much,

Ron

Comment: If you want to map each `PATIENT` element to an `ImportedTable` element then in XSLT that is done through `<xsl:template match="PATIENT"><ImportedTable>...</ImportedTable></xsl:template>`. The dots will do at least `<xsl:copy-of select="descendant::*[not(*)]"/>` plus collecting the preceding elements. Due to the lack of indentation I haven't quite grasped the structure.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Flattening a hierarchical XML is a common task. You simply create an element for each record in the most atomic table and include the data from its parent tables. As it happens, the structure of your example XML input makes this very easy:

**XSLT 1.0**

```
<xsl:stylesheet version="1.0" 
xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform">
<xsl:output method="xml" version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8" indent="yes"/>
<xsl:strip-space elements="*"/>

<xsl:template match="/REPORT">
    <xsl:copy>
        <xsl:variable name="report-data" select="REPORT-DTL/*" />
        <xsl:for-each select="GROUP">
            <xsl:variable name="group-data" select="GROUP-DTL/*" />
            <xsl:for-each select="PROVIDER">
                <xsl:variable name="provider-data" select="PROVIDER-DTL/*" />
                <xsl:for-each select="PATIENT">
                    <ImportedTable>
                        <xsl:copy-of select="$report-data"/>
                        <xsl:copy-of select="$group-data"/>
                        <xsl:copy-of select="$provider-data"/>
                        <xsl:copy-of select="PATIENT-DTL/*"/>
                        <xsl:copy-of select="SERVICE-DTL1/*"/>
                    </ImportedTable>
                </xsl:for-each>
            </xsl:for-each>
        </xsl:for-each>
    </xsl:copy>
</xsl:template>

</xsl:stylesheet>
```

Comment: Yes!! That did it!  Thank you! For anyone coming to this thread in the future, I saved michael.hor257k 's code as an .xsl file (transform.xsl) , then in Visual Basic used this code to save a transformed file:

Application.TransformXML "C:\Path\To\Raw\Xml-to-convert.xml", _
                             "C:\Path\To\XSLT\transform.xsl", _
                             "C:\Path\To\Final\Converted.xml"
Amazing!

Comment: Just realized that my initial example was oversimplified. In the real files, a PATIENT can have multiple SERVICES under him/her on the tree, and I would like each service to appear as its own record. The present code only records first instance of a SERVICE belonging to a PATIENT instead of all the services. Would it be possible to tweak the code to allow a PATIENT to have more than one procedure? To use your terminology, would this mean that <SERVICE-DTL1> is the most atomic table?  Should I start a new thread with a better example? Thanks and sorry for this complication.

Comment: I think you have enough here to make the necessary adaption by yourself.

Comment: You are right. It worked. Here is my new code, following your example and extending to a different "atomic" level. Highlights added to show modifications. It seems to work. [Revised code](https://docs.google.com/document/d/1BH9ILc6BlIS7N_gf7QvM5lfbHG7FzFBqoDNMxWor51s/edit?usp=sharing).